# Elastic Search - Mappings for Fuzzy search

Tags: elasticsearch

The following is the setting applied for a fuzzy search across institutes:

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "edgeNGramFilter": {
                "type": "nGram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20
            },
            "institutes_stopwords": {
                "type": "stop",
                "stopwords": ["College", "University", "Engineering", "of", "Institute", "Technology"]
            },
            "word_joiner": {
                  "type": "word_delimiter",
                  "catenate_all": true
            },
            "specialchars_remover": {
                "type":"pattern_replace",
                "pattern": "[^A-Za-z0-9]",
                "replacement": " "
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "whitespaceAnalyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "institutes_stopwords"
                ]
            },
            "edgeNGramAnalyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "edgeNGramFilter",
                    "institutes_stopwords",
                    "word_joiner",
                    "specialchars_remover"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping is given as,

```
    "list": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type":"string",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "s_no": {
                "type":"string",
                "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "institute": {
                "type": "multi_field",
                "fields": {
                    "institute": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "standard",
                        "index_analyzer": "standard",
                        "search_analyzer": "standard",
                        "filter": "word_joiner",
                        "boost": 10.0
                    },
                    "partial": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "edgeNGramAnalyzer",
                        "index_analyzer": "standard",
                        "filter": "word_joiner",
                        "search_analyzer": "edgeNGramAnalyzer",
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
```

So, when I query the institute names with the following query,

```
{
"query":{
    "match":{
        "institute":{
        "query":"A V C College of Engg",
        "fuzziness":3,
        "minimum_should_match":"-40%",
        "boost":5
        }
    }
}
```

}

It worked better for entirely different institutes; whereas for closely related institutes such as, 'MIT College', some false positives such as 'VIT College' comes up as a top result.

Other Scenarios include:

```
* MVC Engineering College is same as MVC Engg College
* MVC Engineering College is same as M.V.C Engineering College
* MVC Engineering College is same as M V C Engineering College
```

Should I make any changes in settings, or is there any corrections to be done to the query?

Comment: Not sure which version you're using but the `filter` parameter in your mapping is not valid. Also you have `analyzer` + `index_analyzer` + `search_analyzer` and only two of them are right (depending on your ES version)

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Val. It's a custom filter which is quoted in the settings. Currently, I am using ES 2.4.0

Comment: In the mapping of a field, you're only allowed to have `analyzer` (index-time analyzer) and `search_analyzer` (search time analyzer). Fix your mapping and see if that solves your issue. More details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/string.html